# Parse month text using parseDate utility method

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm having trouble parsing a month year string into a date when using the jquery ui 's utility method  $.datepicker.parseDate(format, string, settings). ( https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ )

When I use it like

```
 var dt = $.datepicker.parseDate('MM yy', 'January 2011');
```

I expect it to return a date which equals new Date(2011,00,1), but instead I get an invalid date. Does jqueryui's parseDate support full date string parsing? I can't really find any good docs on this. I expected it to support the full month parsing because the datepicker is able to display it in full month format. I've set up a fiddle* to demonstrate my problem. The core code from the fiddle is below.

*http://jsfiddle.net/mouseoctopus/fvrpG/

```
var text = $('#dateText').val();   

var format = $('#dateFormat').val();

$('#instructions').text('Parse the date [' + text + '] using the format [' + format  +']');

try{
  var dt = $.datepicker.parseDate(format,text);
   $('#result').text(dt);
}catch(exception){ }
```

So my question is.. it possible to parse a full month text using the parseDate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak for jQuery parseDate, but you can use a native JavaScript Date.parse with the full month. The JavaScript function requires a full date though, so you'll need to add 1 in front of the date. It returns a timestamp which you can use it to create a new date.

You can find complete documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Example

```
alert(new Date(Date.parse('1 January 2011')));
```

Comment: very nice.  I can use this. If there's not a more exact solution, I'll accept.